# What's wrong with this method of solving NP problems using a quantum computer?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-computer, computer

As far as we know, Quantum Computers can not solve arbitrary [NP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_(complexity)) problems in polynomial time. I have what appears to be a solution, but it is obviously to simple to be correct, since otherwise the problem would have been solved almost instantly. However, I do not know enough QM to find the error.

The idea is that you prepare a qubit $x$ in the state $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\left|0\right> + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\left|1\right>$, and some other qubits $y_i$, each in an independent state equal to $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\left|0\right> + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\left|1\right>$. Now, solve the NP problem using a non-deterministic turing machine, using the $y_i$ to make the nondeterminstic decisions. If it accepts, apply an operation of $x$ that maps $\left|1\right>$ to $\left|0\right>$ and leaves $\left|0\right>$ unchanged. If it rejects, apply an operation to $x$ that maps $\left|1\right>$ to ${-\left|0\right>}$ and leaves $\left|0\right>$ unchanged. Then all the qubits are observed, and a solution can be extracted from the $y_i$.

It appears that all the rejection paths should cancel out in this scenario. I think the flaw is that the operation applied to $x$ is not physically possible, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: If you don't make this more precise you can claim virtually anything this way.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I don't understand. It's well known that quantum computers can carry out quantum algorithms, and that the medium does not affect computational complexity.

Comment: At the preparation stage, it sounds to me like the preparation of the $y_i$ might already violate no-cloning. This is assuming that "independent" means "separable," and that you care about the phase of the $y_i$.

Comment: @BenCrowell I mean that they are all separate qubits that just so happen to be described by that quantum state. They have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 0):

The operation applied to $x$ is not unitary, making it nonphysical.